# Draw freehand on Android

Tags: android, image-editor

Using paint on Windows, I can edit images and also draw freehand. The default image editing application on Android doesn't support freehand.

I need software that will enable me draw freehand on Android.

Comment: Just a side question… I wonder whether the multi-touch capacitive, rather coarse, touch screens of typical Android devices are up to the task. (For example, Safari on iPhone is only so responsible because it “snaps” fingertips to the hyperlinks in the document.) Even resistive touch screens (which are much less coarse usually) have issues there (the N900 being said to have one of the best of them, at least the neo900.org people say that)… and [this](http://www.fiftythree.com/) uses specialised devices and software, too…

Comment: A recommendation depends on the intention. Do you want to draw a few strokes (e.g. the way to the central station), should your drawing overlap a photo or do you want to paint multi-layered artworks?

Comment: Some folk have done *pretty* impressive things on phone touchscreens. I'm not one of those people ;p

Answer (score 8):

Try this one [SketchBook Mobile Express](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.sketchbookexpress). It is harder than drawing on your pc, but if you have a tablet is a great option.

From their about section. Feautures:

- Full Screen work space with on demand UI
- Multi-touch navigation with a 2500% zoom
- Up to 3 layers you can merge and toggle visibility
- Opacity control on each layer
- Import layer from the Gallery on your device or Camera
- Save to the Gallery on your device
- 6 Preset Brushes, including Flood fill tool
- Synthetic pressure sensitivity (brush fade-off)
- Smooth brush stroking
- Add text to current layer
- Dynamic symmetric drawing
- Color Wheel and Customizable Color Swatches

Here is a version of the same application for Tablets: [GooglePlay](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.adsk.sketchbookhdexpress)

Comment: I have heard that with this app the supported canvas sizes are dependent on the devices screen resolution. Is this still true for the current version?

Comment: @KellyThomas I haven't tried it in different screens. In my 9.7 tablet, I didn't have any problem. I cannot say anything for other screens!